# Datajs: How to modify rel-attribute?

Tags: post, odata, atom-feed, datajs

I'm trying to post linked entries in atom-format to Odata service. Only thing missing from my payload is that rel-attribute should be: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/SOItems". Currently it's automatically generated to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/links"

Heres my current linked entries:

```
<a:link href="SOItems" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/links" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry"><m:inline><a:feed><a:entry><a:author><a:name></a:name></a:author><a:content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:OrderId>0</d:OrderId><d:Item>000020</d:Item><d:Material>M-06</d:Material><d:Plant>1200</d:Plant><d:Quantity>200.000</d:Quantity><d:Description m:null="true"></d:Description><d:UoM m:null="true"></d:UoM><d:Value m:null="true"></d:Value></m:properties></a:content></a:entry><a:entry><a:author><a:name></a:name></a:author><a:content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:OrderId>0</d:OrderId><d:Item>000020</d:Item><d:Material>M-06</d:Material><d:Plant>1200</d:Plant><d:Quantity>200.000</d:Quantity><d:Description m:null="true"></d:Description><d:UoM m:null="true"></d:UoM><d:Value m:null="true"></d:Value></m:properties></a:content></a:entry></a:feed></m:inline></a:link>
```

How can I set rel-attribute for linked entry with datajs.

Thanks,

Br,
RP

Answer (score 0):

the namespace of links "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/links" is hard code on datajs code. Currently there is no public API that the application could use to change it. However, since the datajs is open source, there are still some methods to work around this issue by modifying the datajs code:

a) Change the value of local property “odataRelatedLinksPrefix” in data.js

b) Expose the local variable “odataRelatedLinksPrefix” to be public by adding odata.odataRelatedLinksPrefix = odataRelatedLinksPrefix in data.js code. After doing this, the application could change the namespace value by calling OData.odataRelatedLinksPrefix whenever and wherever.